# fancyhdr is only appearing on the titlepage

Tags: header-footer, titles, fancyhdr

I'm trying to get a small image into the footer of my report. I found online that the best way to do this is by using the `fancyhdr` package. I thus included following code into my `main.text` document, just above the `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Overleaf}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
```

After this piece, the subsequent code follows:

```
\begin{document}

\normallinespacing

\begin{titlepage}
\input{components/titlepage.tex}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Abstract}

[...]
```

Now, the issue is that the fancyhdr style is only applied to the titlepage. It doesn't affect the consecutive pages. It should actually be in the reverse order. `fancyhdr` should only be applied to all pages except the first one.

I created a [sample public project online on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/rrcqnbrtjgsz).

Here's a screenshot of the example title page:
[image]

Here's a screenshot of a random other page:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "random other page" is not a random page, but the first page of a chapter, which uses the `plain` page style. This page style can be changed like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\include{styles/thesis.preamble}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Overleaf}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Overleaf}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
}

\begin{document}

\normallinespacing

\begin{titlepage}
\input{components/titlepage.tex}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Abstract}
\input{content/abstract/abstract.tex}

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{content/introduction/motivation.tex}
\input{content/introduction/problem-definition.tex}
\input{content/introduction/contributions.tex}
\input{content/introduction/structure-of-this-report.tex}

\chapter{Background}
\input{content/background/background.tex}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works!